# XGBoost Bayesian Optimisation in tidymodels

Tags: xgboost, confusion-matrix, hyperparameters, tidymodels, gaussian-process

I try to apply bayesian optimisation to a binary classification problem (XGBOOST) inside the tidymodels framework.

1. Are there any flaws inside my code - the model has run since 2 days on a 72 CPU Linux Machine. Although my dataset is quite big with around 6gb (1 million rows and 2000 columns), I lack the experience to tell If the time for computation is to be expected or if there are any issues that I do not see.

- UPDATE:
  after 2 days I got this output:

```
❯  Generating a set of 10 initial parameter results
✓ Initialization complete


── Iteration 1 ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

i Current best:     roc_auc=0.7634 (@iter 0)
i Gaussian process model
x Gaussian process model: Error in fit_gp(mean_stats %>% dplyr::select(-.iter), pset = param_info, : argument is missing, with no default
Error in `check_gp_failure()`:
! Gaussian process model was not fit.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
✖ Optimization stopped prematurely; returning current results.
> stopCluster(cl)
> doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()
> show_best(myxgb_res, n=25)
# A tibble: 10 × 11
   learn_rate tree_depth min_n loss_reduction .metric .estimator  mean     n std_err .config               .iter
        <dbl>      <int> <int>          <dbl> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>                 <int>
 1       1.34          8     5           34.1 roc_auc binary     0.763    10 0.00125 Preprocessor1_Model01     0
 2       1.49          6     7           64.1 roc_auc binary     0.751    10 0.00165 Preprocessor1_Model05     0
 3       1.53          5     3           12.1 roc_auc binary     0.727    10 0.00204 Preprocessor1_Model03     0
 4       1.35          7     3          356.  roc_auc binary     0.721    10 0.00214 Preprocessor1_Model07     0
 5       1.17          9     4          548.  roc_auc binary     0.704    10 0.00167 Preprocessor1_Model04     0
 6       1.04          9     6         1195.  roc_auc binary     0.685    10 0.00100 Preprocessor1_Model06     0
 7       1.80          6     7        54577.  roc_auc binary     0.5      10 0       Preprocessor1_Model02     0
 8       1.21          4     1         5707.  roc_auc binary     0.5      10 0       Preprocessor1_Model08     0
 9       1.98          8     9        32672.  roc_auc binary     0.5      10 0       Preprocessor1_Model09     0
10       1.74          4     9        10550.  roc_auc binary     0.5      10 0       Preprocessor1_Model10     0
```

Also when I run the code on the example "mtcars" dataset the following error comes up, so I assume that I must miss something

```
❯  Generating a set of 10 initial parameter results
→ A | warning: No control observations were detected in `truth` with control level '1'.
There were issues with some computations   A: x1
✓ Initialization complete


── Iteration 1 ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

i Current best:     roc_auc=0.9167 (@iter 0)
i Gaussian process model
x Gaussian process model: Error in fit_gp(mean_stats %>% dplyr::select(-.iter), pset = param_info, : argument is missing, with no default
Error in `check_gp_failure()`:
! Gaussian process model was not fit.
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
✖ Optimization stopped prematurely; returning current results.
> show_best(myxgb_res, n=10)
# A tibble: 10 × 11
   learn_rate tree_depth min_n loss_reduction .metric .estimator  mean     n std_err .config               .iter
        <dbl>      <int> <int>          <dbl> <chr>   <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>                 <int>
 1     0.108           9     2           3.32 roc_auc binary     0.917     9  0.0589 Preprocessor1_Model02     0
 2     0.0771          7     2           1.22 roc_auc binary     0.917     9  0.0589 Preprocessor1_Model04     0
 3     0.0340          5     4           4.38 roc_auc binary     0.5       9  0      Preprocessor1_Model01     0
 4     0.250           4     7           2.24 roc_auc binary     0.5       9  0      Preprocessor1_Model03     0
 5     0.237          10     5           3.78 roc_auc binary     0.5       9  0      Preprocessor1_Model05     0
 6     0.161           4     6           4.66 roc_auc binary     0.5       9  0      Preprocessor1_Model06     0
 7     0.211           6    10           1.40 roc_auc binary     0.5       9  0      Preprocessor1_Model07     0
 8     0.149           7     9           3.94 roc_auc binary     0.5       9  0      Preprocessor1_Model08     0
 9     0.0417          3     3           2.17 roc_auc binary     0.5       9  0      Preprocessor1_Model09     0
10     0.290           8     8           2.76 roc_auc binary     0.5       9  0      Preprocessor1_Model10     0
>
```

Follow- up- quesiton, that are more general:

2. Which metric should I use to optimise the model if my target variable is slightly imbalanced with a 1/3 ratio. I assume F1 (f_meas) should be the most relevant?

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(tidymodels)
library(doParallel)
library(xgboost)


options(scipen = 999)
# Load example data
data(mtcars)

# Create a binary target
mtcars$am <- as.factor(mtcars$am)

set.seed(123)
df_split <- initial_split(mtcars, strata = am)

df_train <- training(df_split)
df_test <- testing(df_split)
df_train_folds <- vfold_cv(df_train, strata = am)


# /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#prep
recipe_df <- recipe(am ~ ., data=df_train) %>% 
  step_zv(all_predictors()) %>% 
  step_normalize(all_numeric_predictors())

xgb_prep<- prep(recipe_df,verbose=T,)


# Create model

xgb_spec <- boost_tree(
  trees = 100,
  tree_depth = tune(),
  min_n = tune(),
  learn_rate = tune(),
  loss_reduction = tune()
) %>%
  set_engine("xgboost") %>%
  set_mode("classification")


# set ranges for parameters
params <- parameters(
  learn_rate(),
  tree_depth(), 
  min_n(), 
  loss_reduction()
) %>%
  update(
    learn_rate = learn_rate(c(0.01, 0.3), trans=NULL),  # range for the learning rate
    tree_depth = tree_depth(c(3, 10)),  # range for the tree depth
    min_n = min_n(c(1, 10)),  # range for the minimum number of observations
    loss_reduction = loss_reduction(c(1, 5), trans=NULL)  # range for the loss reduction
  ) %>%
  finalize(df_train)

# Merge into workflow
xgb_wf <- workflow() %>% 
  add_model(xgb_spec) %>% 
  add_recipe(xgb_prep)




#Parallel Processing
# gc()
# numCores = 30 #detectCores() 72
# cl = parallel::makeCluster(numCores)
# doParallel::registerDoParallel(cl)
options(tidymodels.dark = TRUE)

myxgb_res <- tune_bayes(
  xgb_wf,
  resamples = df_train_folds,
  param_info = params,
  initial = 10,
  iter = 30, 
  metrics = metric_set(roc_auc),
  control = control_bayes(
    no_improve = 5, 
    save_pred = T, 
    verbose = T,
    seed = 123
  ),
  parallel_over = "everything",
)

# stopCluster(cl)
# doParallel::stopImplicitCluster()

show_best(myxgb_res, n=10)
```

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: How bad is the class imbalance? I suspect that all of your initial values have the same metric value (or a lot of them do). The best ROC from the initial run is 1/2 (pretty bad) and the warning makes me think that you are only giving it data from one class.

Comment: The class imbalance in my originial data is 1:3 and in the reproducable mtcars-data it is 2:3

Comment: Can you separate out the initial values by making a call to `tune_grid()` and show those results? Almost the same code as `tune_bayes()` (plus set the seed before running these.

Comment: I ran: 

`set.seed(123)
init<-tune_grid(xgb_wf,
          resamples = df_train_folds,
          param_info = params,
          grid=10,
          metrics = metric_set(roc_auc),
          control = control_bayes(verbose = T,
                                  save_pred = T)
          )`
and all models have the same ROC. Also please check my update at the top for my original data

Comment: what irritates me aswell is the range of the parameters which should be narrowed down

Comment: So we need a way for any of your models to be able to provide the smallest bit of predictive power; right now there is no signal that they are picking up. You might try down sampling using the themis package or pass `scale_pos_weight` as an engine parameter so that your model is not overfitting to the majority class. You might also stick with grid search; xgboost is pretty easy to optimize (once you have some signal) and sequential optimization is probably a waste of time here.

Comment: Also, your learning rate is really too high. The units in the function call `learn_rate(c(0.01, 0.3))` should be log10 units; you are ranging from 10^.1 (=1.23) to about 10^.3 (about 2). Values around 0.05 to 0.1 are usually a good place to be.

Comment: Thanks so far! Using the `trans=NULL` argument gives me the parameter-range i want. When I apply that to the tune_bayes function i get two initial sets with roc_auc of 0.917 . Also I get the same error message as for my OG-Data:  

`x Gaussian process model: Error in fit_gp(mean_stats %>% dplyr::select(-.iter), pset = param_info, : argument is missing, with no default
Error in `check_gp_failure()`:
! Gaussian process model was not fit.` 

Does this error message tell you something? I would prefer using tune_bayes for the sake of learning it